# html is not rendering my image and the source is correct

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to make the image "id = image" appear but it wont show up. I have done it with a simpler version where all i had was the body and the image tag and it worked but it wont appear in this format

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
      <title>Text To Gif</title>
      <script src="//www.WebRTC-Experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
    </head>

    <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      function onClicked() {
      socket.emit('record');
      socket.on('message', function(data){ 
      document.getElementById('transcript').innerHTML = data; });
      var downloadButton = document.getElementById("search_button");
      var counter = 11;
      id = setInterval(function() {
        counter--;
        if(counter < 0) {
          downloadButton.innerHTML = "Record";
          document.getElementById('transcript').innerHTML = "";
          clearInterval(id);
        } else {
          downloadButton.innerHTML = counter.toString();
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  </script>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Montserrat">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif}
      .w3-bar,h1,button {font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif}
         .fa-anchor,.fa-coffee {font-size:200px}
  </style>

  <body>

  <!-- Header -->
    <div class="w3-container w3-red w3-center" style="padding:250px 16px">
      <h1 class="w3-margin-small w3-jumbo">Click Below To Start</h1>
      <button type="button" onclick="onClicked();" id="search_button" class="w3-button w3-black w3-padding-large w3-large w3-margin-top">Record</button>
      <p id="transcript"></p>
      <img src="C:/Users/vlisn/Documents/speechapi/texttogif/images/cokelogo.png" 
         id="image" width="110" height="107">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

can you help me out? i think it has to do with the code around it not the image tag

Comment: Why is this tagged NodeJS and not JavaScript though?

Comment: because my backend was nodejs but you are correct there is no node js in this file, sorry

Comment: The image source is not correct. File paths like `C:/Users/...` will not work on a web server.

Answer (score 2):

I've edited your question because oh my god my eyes.

Now that I've done it, I see tons of flaws in your HTML. You have `<meta>` tags that are **outside your `<head>`** and they can't/shouldn't be. You are also loading `<link>` outside of it.

Now partially, the issue with rendering could be because you are using a flat out path with `C:/Users/vslin.....`. Try creating a folder called `images` in the same level as your HTML file and copying the image inside there, and then just using something like `src="images/cokelogo.png"`.

It should be working, so the only reasons that seem viable are that you have the HTML file broken with the `<link>` and metas outside the `<head>`, or because of the absolute file pathing instead of relative one.

---

**Edit:** As per @LisaJoseph 's comment, it really seems like the absolute path is the issue here. Running on a server, you can't do `src="C:/User/...."` simply because those folders *do not* exist in your server. What you need to do is relative paths, as such:

```
- ServerFolder
 |- index.html
 |- images/
     |- cokelogo.png
```

And with this structure, you can then just do

```
<img src="images/cokelogo.png">
```

And the server will find it.

Comment: Good job. It hurt my eyes too. And I didn't even notice all that stuff between header and body until now.

Comment: so it works if i just want to render the html but when i run it on the server, it doesnt show up \

Comment: @Palle Due yeah I couldn't see the stuff either.
@LisaJoseph you cannot run with absolute paths on the server, like `C:/user/` because those files aren't in the server. In there you have to do like I said in my third paragraph.

Comment: i changed what u said, the relative path and links and meta, and it still does not appear ;/

Comment: Look at my latest edit on the post. Also, have you put all the files into the head?